# Automatically calculate average rows in excel each time a unique reference number changes

Tags: excel

Is there a way to automatically calculate the average of many rows in excel each time a unique reference number changes?

I have automatically inserted a blank row each time the unique reference changes, and then for the corresponding data for each unique reference (there are varying rows of data for each unique reference (which is a person)), into those blank rows I need to average said rows of data. I am currently doing this manually (autosum average, in the first blank, and dragging across), but I have several hundred rows I need to do this for).

Ok, it won't let me add an image.

I have autoinserted a blank row each time the 'id' changes. And for each set of rows for each ID I need to calculate the average of the column of data above. So ID1 has 5 rows of data for each column (A thru H), and I have manually averaged those 5 rows for 'A' and dragged across. I would like to be able to do this automatically, because I have hundreds of unique IDs each with varying sets of data - but always with the same number of columns.

Comment: Sorry, Can you describe by image?

Comment: How best do I do that? Screenshot?

Comment: Yes, Take a screenshot and write some thing.

Comment: dammit it it didn't show correctly. It won't let me add an image or screenshot

Comment: To do a screenshot (if you can't directly add it), just take a screenshot, save as .jpg and upload to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com).  Then post the URL link to the image in your post.  For the data, say you have rows 1:5, then add a new row. You want the average to now average rows 1:6?

Answer (score 0):

Starting say with something like:

[image: SO32945603 first example]

Select Columns A:H, DATA > Outline - Subtotal, At each change in: `id`, Use function: `Average`, Add subtotal to: check B to H inclusive and Replace current subtotals and Summary below data, to end up with (if applying some formatting I added to try to clarify):

[image: SO32945603 second example]

For the above the `id`s need to be grouped (be in a continuous series for each distinct `id`) but not necessarily in order, though sorting is generally the easiest way to ensure such grouping.

It is not necessary to insert rows between each group before applying Subtotal (which inserts rows automatically to suit), though blank rows may help to distinguish one group from another.